# No Create App button

Tags: facebook, developer-tools

I registered as a developer yesterday and was able to create/delete apps. But after about an hour, when I tried to create a new app on developers.facebook.com/apps I do not see the 'Create new App' button on the top right.

Can someone please help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found the answer in another post, hope it helps. http://developers.facebook.com/setup